# Imagick::paintTransparentImage method is deprecated and it's use should be avoided

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, imagick

I am trying to run Imagick within Laravel 5 and I keep getting this error every time I try and run my code. `Imagick::paintTransparentImage` method is deprecated and it's use should be avoided. Before when I was running the code without Laravel this was a warning but the function would still run. Is there any way to suppress or turn off this warning? All other Imagick functions work great, and this one does if run outside the context of Laravel.

Comment: Why not look for the alternative to the deprecated method and implement that instead?

Comment: Either suppress the error with @  or change the code to use http://phpimagick.com/Imagick/opaquePaintImage ?

Answer (score 2):

as you mentioned, Imagick::paintTransparentImage method is deprecated.

Use Imagick::transparentPaintImage instead.

http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.transparentpaintimage.php

Answer (score 1):

I ended up turning turning down the php error reporting strictness and the code runs fine. If anyone else gets this message do not freak out, it is depreciated but they have NOT provided an up to date alternative, opaquePaintImage is NOT the same thing.